# How to track analytics for email client usage?

Tags: email, analytics, html-email, email-client

I just found [this link](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/email-clients/) on Campaign Monitor's website that mentions they can provide detailed analytics of which email clients people are using. I was under the impression that this wasn't possible. How do they do this? How can I write my own script to be able to determine this in my own HTML email campaigns?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an embedded image which links to a .aspx file that can then take a query string from the end of the image src and add information into a database. Its a bit too complicated to explain in a single question.